# Как установить формат сериализации данных по умолчания для аннотации Spring @ResponseBody?

Tags: java, json, xml, spring

Использую аннотацию уровня класса @RestController, которая, включает в себя @ResponseBody. В итоге, если в заголовке запроса, либо в атрибутах специально не указать *application/json*, Spring автоматически сериализует в ответе мою сущность в формат xml. 
Пробовал переопределить конфигурацию в своём классе WebConfig

```
@Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        converters.add(customJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        converters.add(customJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());


        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter customJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
        jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
        return jsonConverter;
    }

    @Bean
    public MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter customJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter();
        ObjectMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
        xmlConverter.setObjectMapper(xmlMapper);
        return xmlConverter;
    }
```

Однако, никакого эффекта нет, Spring как-будто имеет где-то свой конфиг, который более приоритетный и даже если удалить весь вышеприведённый код, он будет исправно сериализовывать сущность в xml/json.
Над сущностью стоит аннотация @JsonAutoDetect.

Код контроллера:

```
        @RestController
        public class MyController {

        @RequestMapping(value = "get_messages/{id}")
        public MyEntity getEntity(some params..) {
        return myServise.getEntity
    }
}
```

Мой вопрос: как изменить настройки сериализации с помощью @ResponseBody по-умолчанию. Чтобы, если в запросе не пришло никаких параметров (xml/json), авто-сериализация производилась именно в json, а не в xml, как сейчас.

Comment: Попробуйте над классом-контроллером добавить: 
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourPath", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло, добавил produces = {APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, APPLICATION_XML_VALUE}. Теперь по дефолту мапит в json, а если явно указать в хедере запроса xml - то и в xml.
Если оформите как ответ, отмечу его решением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Над классом-контроллером необходимо добавить: @RequestMapping(value = "/yourPath", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE).